# Concatenate heterogeneous lists based on 2-tuples

Tags: rust, tuples, concatenation

Consider lisp-like heterogeneous 'lists' based on 2-tuples:

```
let a = (); // ()
let b = (1i32, ('2', ("3", (4u64, ())))); // (1i32 '2' "3", 4u64)
```

I want to concatenate them like so:

```
let a = (1, ('2', ()));
let b = ("3", (4, ()));
let c = concat(a, b); // (1, ('2', ("3", (4, ()))));
```

I have managed to do so in what I believe to be an excessively convoluted way:

```
impl<Other> Concat<Other> for () {
    type Result = Other;

    fn concat(self, other: Other) -> Self::Result {
        other
    }
}

impl<Head, Tail, Other> Concat<Other> for (Head, Tail)
    where Tail: Concat<Other>
{
    type Result = (Head, <Tail as Concat<Other>>::Result);

    fn concat(self, other: Other) -> Self::Result {
        let (head, tail) = self;
        (head, tail.concat(other))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = (1, ('2', ()));
    let b = ("3", (4, ()));
    println!("{:?}", a.concat(b));  // (1, ('2', ("3", (4, ()))));
}
```

Can we do better? If so, how?

Comment: That's actually quite beautiful (as far as I am concerned). The main issue I see is that probably other functionalities (taking the head, the tail, etc...) will require new traits each time, but otherwise it's pretty nice!

Comment: I think this belongs on codereview, because you have a working solution, asking to improve on it is out of scope for stackoverflow.